# Default view for an area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.  I created an area called `Administration`.  There is no default view associated with it, so if I type in www.mywebsite.com/Administration then there is an error.  How would I go and define a default view when the user types in the above mentioned URL?  Would I need to go and create a Home controller?

I would like to have something like:
www.mywebsite.com/Administration or
www.mywebsite.com/Administration/Index

`AdministrationAreaRegistration.cs` has the following:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
   context.MapRoute(
      "Administration_default",
      "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
}
```

Not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are about not to define default view, but default action. The code above misses the type of controller, action of which you want to use as default:

Suppose you have `AdministrationHome` controller.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
   context.MapRoute(
      "Administration_default",
      "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { action = "Index", controller="AdministrationHome", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps make a Controller/Views called Administration in the root (not in the Administration area).

Call the view `index`.